# Nullpointer exception in method call by RPC

Tags: java, methods, gwt, nullpointerexception, rpc

Getting nullpointer exception while invoking a method from different class

```
 public ArrayList<String> getSelectionTableView(String recievedToDate, String recievedFromDate) {

        ArrayList<String> response = new ArrayList<String>();
        SelectionTable sobj = null;
        response= sobj.selectionTableValue(recievedToDate, recievedFromDate);
        return response;
}
```

In this SelectionTable class is just making a JDBC connection and processing a Select query and returning the result in an array list. SelectionTable class is working fine(I have tested it separately ). 
I am getting nullpointer exception in method call. While debugging ,as the iteration reaches the method call, it is getting directed to below java method:

```
public InvocationTargetException(Throwable target) {
    super((Throwable)null);  // Disallow initCause
    this.target = target;
}
```

and I am getting below Errors:

com.iti.gwtproject.pcmaintenancelog.client.service.CustomService.getSelectionTableView(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NullPointerException

FYI: getSelectionTableView method is getting invoked by a RPC call.

Comment: on line 4 you set `sobj` to null, so invoking a method on it always throws a `NPE`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

```
    SelectionTable sobj = null;
    response= sobj.selectionTableValue(recievedToDate, recievedFromDate);
```

There you go. `sobj` is always null when you try to call `selectionTableValue` on it...

Answer (score 0):

As Mark mentioned:

```
SelectionTable sobj = null;
```

So the object will always be null when u call the `selectionTableValue` on the `sobj`object.

Maybe you could try making a constructor in the `SelectionTable` to initialize a `null` object.

Or maybe a noob solution, you dont require that statement at all. xD

Comment: even if I am removing SelectionTable sobj = null; and calling cunstructor of SelectionTable I am facing same problem.Now edited code is : [response= selectionTableobj.SelectionTable(recievedToDate, recievedFromDate);]